# Considering cross correlation with timestamp

Tags: r, time-series, cross-correlation

As far as I understood, to compute the cross correlation between two time series, we just consider the values of the time series, i.e, cross correlation ignores the timestamps of each data points in the time series. For example, suppose that we have the following time series:

```
> ts1
             dateTime value
1 2018-04-27 00:00:00     6
2 2018-04-27 00:00:01     2
3 2018-04-27 00:00:04     3
4 2018-04-27 00:00:05     1
> ts2
             dateTime value
1 2018-04-27 00:00:00     3
2 2018-04-27 00:00:01     8
3 2018-04-27 00:00:02     4
4 2018-04-27 00:00:03     5
5 2018-04-27 00:00:04     2
6 2018-04-27 00:00:05     4
```

At time lag 0, cross correlation considers the correlation between data points even they do not have same timestamps. For example at time lag 0, cross correlation considers the correlation between the third row of `ts1` whose `dateTime` is `00:00:04` with the third row of of `ts2` whose `dateTime` is `00:00:02`. It seems that cross correlation completely ignores the `dateTime` and only considers the values of data points. But I would like to consider the correlation between the third row of `ts1` with the fifth row of `ts2`. In this case, both of them have same `dateTime` value which is `00:00:04`. Is there a better way to do that rather than imputing missing values for `ts1`?